# Is Wikipedia in violation of GNU Free Documentation License?

Tags: copyright, licensing, creative-commons, copyright-notice, authorship

Consider [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant). The main photo on the right ("A female African bush elephant in Mikumi National Park, Tanzania") is [licensed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:African_Bush_Elephant.jpg) under the `GNU Free Documentation License version 1.2`. However:

1. in the article itself, there is no mention of `GNU FDL` nor of the copyright nor of the image author, even though "attribution of the image to the author" is "required in a prominent location near to the image"
2. at the bottom of the article page it says: `Text is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License 4.0`, even though `GNU FDL` requires that all the derived works (so for example: works containing `GNU FDL` licensed content, with or without modification) be licensed under the same license (`GNU FDL`).

What am I missing?

Or is it, that Wikipedia has a separate licensing agreement with the original author of this elephant photo, and hence is not bound by the terms of `GNU FDL`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the GNU Free Documentation License is not a law.

Comment: @bdb484 is is a legal question though, and `GNU Free Documentation License` would be void should there be no copyright law.

Comment: I'd call it a contract-interpretation question, but not a legal question.

Comment: The GNU FDL does not say that the attribution must be "in a prominent location near to the image/document". If you read section 2, FDL merely says that you must include the FDL, the copyright notices, and a statement that the FDL applies to the document (i.e. to the image). Wikipedia appears to include all of those things as soon as you click the image of the elephant. I don't think they're trying to hide it -- this is pretty standard web page behaviour. If it were a printed document, you'd probably better mention it in a footnote somewhere. But on the web, a link seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreted strictly, yes, this is a violation of the GFDL. That's also the reason why this license (with few exceptions) is no longer acceptable on Wikipedia/Commons for images and many older images have been relicensed as CC-By-sa. I can't currently find it, but IIRC WMF argues that the single click necessary to get to the license is acceptably close to the GFDL requirement, even if not literally sufficient.

Wmf and the community clearly dislike uploaders who use a difficult-to-follow license to trick users of their images into lawsuits or financial claims. Photographers have been blocked for that and their (otherwise good) images have been deleted.

Comment: The article only puts the **text** under CC-A-SA, **not** any photos.

Comment: Good point @Trish, but if the article page containing an `GNU FDL` image is a derived work, then, according to `GNU FDL`, if **must** be licensed under `GNU FDL` too. Correct? Or what is the license of the article **webpage** in this case?

Comment: @stf what makes the text a derivate of the image?

Comment: @Trish I don't quite get your point. In said "Elephant" article, the text is CC-BY-SA, but the top image of the Elephant is GFDL. That's exactly the point of the question. GFDL has some requirements, which would basically not allow embedding the image in the way it's currently done (and not least because of this it is no longer considered a suitable license for images).

Comment: @stf The GNU FDL explicitly says in section 7 that you're allowed to combine (or "aggregate") other works with the FDL work, and that doing so does not automatically mean that the other works must be licensed as FDL as well. It seems unlikely that the text in the Wikipedia is somehow derivative of the photo.

Comment: If I visit the photo page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:African_Bush_Elephant.jpg, then I can see that there is a copy of the FDL "included" on that page, in the form of a hyperlink to another Wikipedia page -- since that is still part of Wikipedia, I think that still counts as "including" the license for the purposes of fulfilling the FDL. Also, sections 5 and 6 of the FDL mention that it is sufficient to include a single copy of the FDL to cover the requirement for all the FDL-licensed works that are in your combination/collection. So it's not clear to me why this would be a violation.

Comment: @Brandin The problem is that the article page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant does not include the FDL or any reference to it until you click the elephant.

Comment: @PMF That's another way of saying that the license text *is* included, although on a different physical page -- for a web page, the fact that you click on links to navigate is part of how the HTML format works. If this were a printed book, we'd be reasonable to expect the reader to refer to the table of contents to see on which page the FDL license text is to be found, and then to flip to that page (e.g. in the appendix) to find the required text. Those actions of flipping to a page are analogous to mouse clicks on a web page.

Comment: @Brandin I don't recall the full discussion, but see the second point [under Motivation here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Licensing_update&uselang=en): The GFDL has some provisions that where ambiguous and hard to follow unless you had an army of lawyers at your disposal. And there where people who sued users of their images if they didn't follow the license to the very last letter. This is not in line with Wikimedia's goals.

Comment: @Trish I think you're right: the **text** is **not** a derivative of the **image**. But the article **webpage** is a derivative of both the **image** and the **text** (because it contains both). Now, `GFDL` (of the **image**) requires the **webpage** to be put under `GFDL`, and, similarly, `CC BY-SA` (of the **text**) requires the **webpage** to be put under `CC BY-SA` (thanks to the similar `Share Alike` clause). Those two licenses are not the same, so, what is the final license of the **webpage**?